# falco docker containers monitoring

Tags: falco

Can any one of you please tell me where I can find the way to monitor docker images with falco? Now I'm using Ubuntu for testing purposes, but in the end I want to use it in AWS Fargate environment.

Thanks

Help on this from the community

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Falco docs](https://falco.org/docs/getting-started/running/#docker-least-privileged):

> To run Falco in a container using Docker with full privileges use the
> following commands. If you want to use Falco with the Kernel module
> driver:
>
> ```
> docker pull falcosecurity/falco:latest
>
> docker run --rm -i -t \
>     --privileged \
>     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock \
>     -v /dev:/host/dev \
>     -v /proc:/host/proc:ro \
>     -v /boot:/host/boot:ro \
>     -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro \
>     -v /usr:/host/usr:ro \
>     -v /etc:/host/etc:ro \
>     falcosecurity/falco:latest
> ```